# Run a .jar on Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, jar, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to run a .jar file on Heroku, and can't find instructions anywhere on how to do this. Everything that I have read wants me to compile it as I am uploading it to Heroku. Is this possible, and if it is, how would I do this?

If it helps, I am trying to run a Minecraft Craftbukkit server, and I don't have a pom.xml file yet.

Comment: Could you explain more specific what it is you want to achieve?

Comment: I've tried to answer your question bellow but as @Max said, you need to be more specific about what is your goal, environment and accomplishments. For further questions consider taking a look first at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi. Did you solve your question? If not, I think that your server is a war file instead jar. DO you have some link? A github link, could be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't provide much details but I'll try to give you and people who reaches this question with a way to do it.

First of all, create a Heroku account and create a heroku application (assumed you have already done that).

Second, you need to generate you application jar and upload it to Heroku. To do so, open a terminal and install heroku cli (assuming a unix terminal):

$ sudo npm install -g heroku-cli

You need to have npm and nodejs installed, you can check this link:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04

Once done that, you can use npm to update to a node version that is acceptable by heroku-cli:

$ sudo npm install -g n
$ sudo n 7.10.0

and than run:

$ sudo npm install -g heroku-cli

In order to deploy jars, you need to install the deploy plugin:

$ sudo heroku plugins:install heroku-cli-deploy

Than you're abble to authenticate the heroku-cli with your heroku credentials using:

$ heroku login

And finally run the deploy command:

$ heroku deploy:jar path/to/target/myproject.jar --app YOU_HEROKU_APP_NAME

Please feel free to ask further questions if I've forgot something or this is not specific to you environment, but those steps will give you a good base to solve you problem!

Hope it helps!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

maybe too late but for ones who are coming today, this is how you do it:

1. install cli `heroku plugins:install heroku-cli-deploy`
2. create app `heroku create --no-remote`
3. deploy jar using app name you got from step 2 `heroku deploy:jar target/my-app.jar --app <app_name>`

Ref: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-executable-jar-files

Comment: can you tell me what is --no-remote ? is -no-remote the app name?

Answer (score 1):

Webapp Runner allows you to launch an application in a Tomcat container on any computer that has a JRE installed. No previous steps to install Tomcat are required when using Webapp Runner. It’s just a jar file that can be executed and configured using the java command.

The article [Deploying Tomcat-based Java Web Applications with Webapp Runner](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner) will walk you through building an application that launches with Webapp Runner and deploying that application to Heroku.